# Set the Bold functionality on by default when adding Header or Paragraph in WordpressGutenberg/Block? Thank you for the reply

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

When adding a header or a paragraph block in WP Gutenberg/Block, I need the Bold icon/functionality to be on by default and the strong tag added when I type/enter the text?

We need the Bold icon/functionality to be on before typing any text. Is this possible Sirs? If yes, please share links/examples on how to achieve this programmatically.

I researched and googled for several hours/days but I can't seem to find anything online that can help us achieve this.

Thank you in advance for the replies.

[image]

Comment: Is the reason for requiring `<strong/>` on everything for visual appearance only or do you need the tag in markup for another purpose? If you want to make entire paragraphs or heading bold, it sounds like it should be CSS or a block style - have you tried block styles?

Comment: we want the bold functionality to be on by default when typing titles sir. thank you for replying @S.Walsh noted on the block styles sir.